# Rsync - Outputting an incremental backup result to a different folder?

Tags: rsync

I am a beginner with the Unix system so please bear with me if this sounds noobish.

The most common way to use rsync to do an incremental backup is to do it like this

```
rsync -av --delete <source> <destination>
```

Is there a way to do it in such a way that you compare directory1 with directory2 but then store the output in directory3?

Basically, what I want is to have a series of daily incremental backups with one full backup to use as the base.

So if I have these folders and today is `20130103`,

```
/folder/to/back/up <-- source
/backup/base <-- base
/backup/20130101 <-- incremental
/backup/20130102 <-- incremental
```

I want to compare `/folder/to/back/up` with `/backup/base` and store the result in a new folder, `/backup/20130103`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/), which is a wrapper around rsync and a couple other tools. It automates building an incremental backup structure that is very close to what you're wanting.

Comment: I will try to look into this. As I said, I am just a newbie in Unix. When I googled for answers, the most common suggestion is to use rsync so I went with it.

Comment: UPDATE: I can't use rsnapshot since the machine where I plan to implement does not have it and I don't have permission to install it.

Comment: @arvinsim - Well, in that case, this question is off-topic, as you are not the administrator of the system in question.

Comment: I was not aware that I needed to be a sysadmin to post here. If that is true, I will move this to stackoverflow.

Comment: @arvinsim - the FAQ states as much. Anyway, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better home than SO. I'll vote to migrate over there - please don't re-post.

Answer (score 1):

The [rsync flags](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) to look at are

> ```
> --compare-dest=DIR      also compare received files relative to DIR
> --copy-dest=DIR         ... and include copies of unchanged files
> --link-dest=DIR         hardlink to files in DIR when unchanged
> ```

[For example](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html):

> rsync -aP --link-dest=PATHTO/$PREVIOUSBACKUP $SOURCE $CURRENTBACKUP

The basic principle of that article ("Time Machine for every Unix out there") has been implemented in many different ways by many different programs, rsnapshot being yet another of them.

[Dirvish](http://dirvish.org) deserves special mention (the original author contributed the `--link-dest` patch to rsync); it's a Perl backup system utilising rsync and hardlinks (similar to rsnapshot) with datestamped destination folders, variable expiry rules, exclude rules etc.; since it uses hardlinks, every backup appears in the filesystem as a "full backup" but only the "incremental" changes are copied.

If you have (or can install) Perl, I'd strongly suggest Dirvish for what you want.

Comment: so basically, set `--link-dest` to `/backup/base`, `<source>` to `/folder/to/back/up` and `<destination>`  to `/backup/20130103`?

Comment: @arvinsim Most likely yes; I'll add some examples to my answer.